# Android appcompat selectableItemBackground crashed in list item view

Tags: android, android-layout, attributes, attr, listviewitem

I have a trouble with android attribute in XML.

I'm working with Material Design and use AppCompat-v7 support library.When I use RecyclerView as collection container,that I want implement listSelector and it's have ripple effect.I found out a way that set item view background use "selectableItemBackground" attribute . And When I set background use "?attr/selectableItemBackground" then launch application ,it's crash:
This is my item view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

PS: When I set ?attr/selectableItemBackground value to activity's layout view(which pass to setContentView(int resID) method layout.) ,It's work fine 
It can be found .But why list item view can't found the attribute..

And I was debug it,that found view.getContext().getTheme() is not same with activity theme,Why

======Code=======

```
System.out.println("list itemview theme:"+ view.getContext().getTheme());

System.out.println("activity view theme:" + mListView.getContext().getTheme());

System.out.println("  activity    theme:" + getTheme());
```

======Result=======

```
12-26 04:41:39.761: I/System.out(4900): list itemview theme:android.content.res.Resources$Theme@3e638d18
12-26 04:41:39.761: I/System.out(4900): activity view theme:android.content.res.Resources$Theme@1df09371
12-26 04:41:39.761: I/System.out(4900):   activity    theme:android.content.res.Resources$Theme@1df09371
```

Please help me ,Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have resolved this problem.It's my mistake that use application context to inflate xml. It's should to use activity as context, Because my custom theme just set to activity.